On click - clear state of buttons then set state of current button to true - React
I am new to react and I am trying to add aria-labels to my buttons that show their state to improve accessibility. I am currently able to change the state when the button is clicked but it accidentally changes the state of all the buttons. I know I need to attach an id to the buttons but I could use some help to show me where I am going wrong.
Here is the code I currently have:
import React, { useState} from 'react'
import './suggestedSearches.scss'

const SuggestedSearches = ({ suggestedSearches, query, setQuery, seachButtonRef }) => {
  const { label, suggestions } = suggestedSearches
  const [ariaPressedId, setAriaPressedId] = useState(-1);
  const toggleAria = (id) => {
    setAriaPressedId(id)
  }

  const handleOnClick = (event, id) => {
    const buttonValue = event.currentTarget.value
    setQuery(buttonValue)
    setTimeout(() => seachButtonRef.current.click())
    toggleAria(id)
  }

  return (
    <>
      {(suggestions && suggestions.length > 0) &&
        <div className='suggested-searches'>
          <h3 className='label'>{label}</h3>
          <div className='suggested-buttons'>
            {suggestions.map((suggestion) => (
              <button
                key={suggestion}
                value={suggestion}
                className={`suggested-button ${suggestion === query ? 'selected' : ''}`}
                onClick={(e) => handleOnClick(e, suggestion.id)}
                aria-pressed={ariaPressedId === suggestion.id}
              >
                {suggestion}
              </button>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>}
    </>
  )
}

export default SuggestedSearches



The intended functionality would be that when a button is clicked the "aria-pressed" state of all the buttons is cleared and then the "aria-pressed" of the current button is set to true.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!


The intended functionality would be that when a button is clicked the "aria-pressed" state of all the buttons is cleared and then the "aria-pressed" of the current button is set to true.

You need not maintain the state with aria-pressed values of all buttons for this use case.
You can have a state to keep track of the id of button whose's aria-pressed is supposed to be true. You can use the state ariaPressedId, set the default value to -1 maybe.
Now when setting the value of aria-pressed of the button, you can set the logic as:
aria-pressed={ariaPressedId === suggestion.id}

This way only this button's aria-pressed value will be true, rest will be false.
This is how the toggleAria function will look like :
const toggleAria = (id) => {
    setAriaPressedId(id)
  }

And in handleOnClick, you'd have to pass the id to the toggleAria:
const handleOnClick = (event, id) => {
    const buttonValue = event.currentTarget.value
    setQuery(buttonValue)
    setTimeout(() => seachButtonRef.current.click())
    toggleAria(id)
  }

So in the onClick of the button will look like this:
onClick={(e) => handleOnClick(e, suggestion.id)}

I hope this answer's your question.

I have amended the code to incorporate your suggestions but I'm still getting the same results. I have amended the question so you can see the new code. Many thanks

I have actually managed to get the desired behavior by adding aria-pressed={`${suggestion === query ? 'true' : 'false'}`}
